# Mapping UNIX Pipe to C++ std::cout

Tags: c++, unix, pipe, stdout

I am researching options of communicating processes in C++. Started with idea to bind Unix pipe to std::cout, but I could get it work. When writing directly using write(STDOUT_FILENO), I get expected result. When writing using std::cout, I get smaller and random output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const int PIPE_READ = 0;
const int PIPE_WRITE = 1;

int main() {
    int pfd[2];

    if(pipe(pfd) == -1){
        std::cout << "Cannot create pipe" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1){
        std::cout << "Error on fork: " << errno << std::endl;
    } else if(pid == 0) { // Child process
        if(dup2(pfd[PIPE_WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO) < 0) {
            std::cout << "Cannot redirect STDOUT: " << errno << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        close(pfd[PIPE_WRITE]);

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            int data = i;
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,&data,sizeof(int)); // Works
            //std::cout << data; // Don't work
        }
    } else { // Parent process
        close(pfd[PIPE_WRITE]);
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            int data;
            ssize_t status;
            if((status = read(pfd[PIPE_READ],&data,sizeof(int))) != sizeof(int)) {
                std::cout << "Error (" << errno << ") on read: " << status << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at your writing:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO,&data,sizeof(int)); // Works
//std::cout << data; // Don't work
```

The first "working" version write the contents of `data` in raw binary form to standard output. The second "non-working" version write the value of `data` ***as text*** to standard output.

If the value of `data` is `5` then the `write` call will write the integer value `5` while `std::cout << data` will write the integer value `53` (using [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)).

This of course have implications when you read the data as a raw and binary `int` in the parent.

If you want write the raw binary data to `std::cout` you have to use [`std::ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write):

```
std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof data);
```

The above line is equivalent to the `write` system-call you have.

---

Also important to know is that writing an `int` in raw form will write `sizeof(int)` bytes, usually four. Writing a single-digit integer as text will write a single byte.

Your loop will write eight numbers, which means it will write 32 bytes (4 * 8) if using `write`. If you output using `<<` to `std::cout` then you will write 8 bytes. When you read you will read those 8 bytes and put into two single `int` values, then the `read` call will return `0` because the pipe has been closed.

What the values of those two `int` values will be depends on your hardware architecture, if it's [little-endian or big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Small mistake :). My assumption was that cout can output both string and binary data depending on provided data type. Another one was that change in file descriptors was not reflected in C++ std::cout object. Thanks.